# .NET Windows console authenticate to php web server and consume REST securely

Tags: c#, .net, rest, file-upload, https

I **need** to have a **client .NET console** application, that **will authenticate** to a **php web server**, **consume** some of it's **REST** services, and **upload to it a file**.

Now the problem is that the authentication at least must be secure (SSL, HTTPS ...), better all requests.

For .NET client I found that there is **HttpWebRequest** available, but I **don't know** how to **make it** use a **secure connection**, and **after** that **query** the **REST** **also securely**, and **upload securely the files**.

**As I understood** based on my current researches, after authentication, the php server must generate a random key, that will be used for the next request to authenticate the user and generate another and so on. But this means no encrypted connection after first authentication?

Also, **the upload** can be done as **post body content**, or **webRequest.upload** even easier, **but** I don't know **how I can make this a secure connection**.

**I'm new to Web development** and I don't fully understand how all this works behind the scenes, pls help me how to do it right.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to handle security with what you are asking. However, it should be at the very least done over SSL. From there, a typical way of handling this is either your site offers a developer signup process that either sends an API token via email, or generates one and when developers log in they can access them from there. They would then use the API token in all API calls.

Another way (still over SSL) is to provide a similar login mechanism like any typical web site... where by you provide Basic Auth username:password creds, then return as a response an OAUTH or other type of token. The client would then send that token with each request. The server can control how long it lasts, or even.. as you mentioned.. if it should generate a new token on every request.

It's quite a large topic however, one you might be best doing some searching on to really provide more complete answers.

Comment: I accepted the answer, even it is not 100% what I was expecting. Thank you!